# PubNub Error: Maximum channel group count exceeded

Tags: node.js, pubnub

I am getting "Maximum channel group count exceeded" when trying to add channels to channel group (using JavaScript/NodeJS).

```
pubnub.channel_group_add_channel({
    callback: resolve,
    error: reject,
    channel_group: pubnubChannelGroup,
    channel: difference.join(',')
});
```

Problem is I am getting "Maximum channel group count exceeded". From https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/540/is-there-a-limit-to-the-number-of-channel-groups-in-my-pubnub-key-set, I understand new keys have unlimited channel groups but no namespaces. But when I try creating a new key

[image]

I still get the error ... why might that be. I've contacted support before to make my key unlimited before. But I have new keys and I wonder why it still does not work.

Comment: When you contact support they will only apply this to one of your Subscribe Keys. It only counts for the Subscribe Key PubNub Support applies it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## How to enable Unlimited PubNub Channel Groups

This should be on by default.  However if it is not you need to contact ***`support@pubnub.com`*** to enable infinite channel groups for **Old PubNub Keys** only.  Send your **~Subscribe Key~**.  When you contact support they will only apply this to one of your Subscribe Keys.  It only counts for the Subscribe Key PubNub Support applies it to.

All newly created API keys will automatically have **Infinity Channel Groups**.  If they don't then something is wrong and you need to contact support.

> Only your ***PubNub Administrator*** can click the **"Disable ChannelGroup Indexing"** checkbox.  This will allow you to get unlimited channel groups.

[image: PubNub Channel Groups]

Comment: I am getting this error but do not have this option.

Comment: contact support@pubnub.com to fix!